# done any activity from consecutive days calculation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want to get from today how many days consecutively  a user did a activity consecutively.
1 .like if he has not done any activity yesterday then count will be only for today 1.
2. from today it will count until user did not done any activity to that day. for example he not done any activity before 5 days but done after that daily . so my consecutive days count is 4 .

my database have 3 columns   user_id , last_update_on , activity_type . so I am keeping record this way  peter have done a activity type read at  `1654206457`  (epoch time). so how I can get my consecutive days from it in dynamo-db

Comment: You may need to read them one day at a time in a loop (from today to some unspecified day in the past, decrementing the date each time) until you fail to read an item for a given day. Also, you should probably store the date as a Julian day number in addition to the epoch timestamp, and query on user id plus Julian date (possibly via a custom GSI on user_id + julian_date).

Comment: Another option is to include a count of consecutive days with each activity that you write. Before you write today's activity, query for yesterday's activity for this user - if found then increment the consecutive_days value from that item and store it in today's item; if not found then store 1 in consecutive_days. This won't work well if you need to be able to delete arbitrary activities after they are written, however.

Comment: You don't mention your scale here, your performance requirements, and the frequency of doing the query, nor what other requirements the database has to support. That stuff matters. There isn't a "perfect" way to do this in DynamoDB so any design is going to involve a tradeoff. But in general think of "how would I keep track of this in the database so that I can just ask for it" rather than "how can I ask the database to do a bunch of work for me". DynamoDB isn't a database designed to ask deep questions against the full set of data.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is designed to be a scalable LOOKUP database and not an analytical one. Even if you find a way to do it (which you surely can) it will not be efficient nor cheap.

The best practice for running analytical queries on data in DynamoDB is to export it to S3 or replicate it to S3 using DynamoDB streams. Then you can query the data from S3 using Athena. In Athena, you have powerful analytical SQL that can answer the current analytical query you have now, and many others that you will have in the future.

Here is a guide to doing the export: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-export-amazon-dynamodb-table-data-to-data-lake-amazon-s3/. You can automate this flow and schedule it to run every day.

Here is a guide to doing the streaming: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/streaming-amazon-dynamodb-data-into-a-centralized-data-lake/. It is a bit more complicated than the export option, however, you will have the most recent data in your queries, if this is important for you.